Cannot find anaconda or python after installation. I cannot launch them
I have tried to install the Anaconda distribution. Once the installation is done it launches Anaconda Navigator and so far everything looks fine. But if I close all the windows, I cannot find any shortcut or app related to Anaconda. The prompt command does not find it either. Basically, I cannot launch the software. I reinstalled it multiple times at this point.
I tried to install Python separately (after uninstalling Anaconda) and the same happened. I cannot find Python anywhere to launch it!
Does anyone know how to help me out?
I am a Windows user.
I could not find online help that seems to be for this particular issue.

during setup, it asks you where you want to install anaconda. If you ahvn't changed anything, it should be installed in the default directory, see https://docs.anaconda.com/free/working-with-conda/reference/faq/ under "What is the default path for installing Anaconda?" to find out the default install locations

Thank you. Indeed, it gets installed in the default directory and I can access that directory. However, I do not find or see the icon to launch the app anywhere there. There is one that says "anaconda" that opens an anaconda console but it immediately closes again and nothing happens.
